# Xamarin.Android - "resolveURI failed on bad bitmap URI" after parsing encoded string

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, uri

I am trying to display an image from a local URI when this activity begins.

The user selects an image, triggering the `OnActivityResult()` method. When I first obtain the URI, it displays the image with no problem:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == IMG_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Result.Ok)
    {
        Android.Net.Uri imageUri = null;
        if (data != null)
        {
            imageUri = data.Data;
            userPreferences.BackgroundImageURI = imageUri.ToString();
            imgView.SetImageURI(imageUri);
            imgView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am storing the URI as an encoded string in `userPreferences`. This is saved to the device, and can be loaded with no issue. In this case the string is `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A38`, and it is identical when loaded from memory (using Shared Preferences).

Here is my code for loading the encoded URI string, parsing the string to create a URI, and then setting URI of `imgView` to display that image.

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
 {
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Preferences);

    userPreferences = Helpers.LoadUserPreferences(this, new Shared.Model.UserPreferences());

    imgView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgView);
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userPreferences.BackgroundImageURI))
    {
        var imgURI = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(userPreferences.BackgroundImageURI);
        imgView.SetImageURI(imgURI);
        imgView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        imgView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
    }
}
```

When it gets to the `SetView(imgUri)` line, I receive this output: `resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A38`

I have even tried hard-coding the URI to no avail. The main frustration is that the code is identical, just running in two different scenarios. Is it possible that it has to do with the Activity lifecycle? Or have I missed something bigger?

Comment: The image that comes on OnActivityResult is from gallery?

Comment: @jzeferino That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userPreferences.BackgroundImageURI))
{
    var imgURI = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(userPreferences.BackgroundImageURI);
    var input = Activity.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(imgURI);
    imgView.SetImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(input));
    imgView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
}
else
{
    imgView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
}
```

---

**As alternative** I have a class that get the real path for the image from a URI. It could be great if you want to give that path to a `CropActivity` for example.

You can download the class from [here](https://gist.github.com/jzeferino/6ee837381ec1c78b383960026c9d784b).

And use it like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userPreferences.BackgroundImageURI))
{
    var imgURI = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(userPreferences.BackgroundImageURI);
    imgView.SetImageURI (Uri.Parse(PathUtils.PathUtils.GetPath(Activity, imgURI)));
    imgView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
}
else
{
    imgView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
}
```

Comment: This actually worked perfectly! I'm not sure that I completely understand it though. So, the URI returned from the `Intent data` above isn't the true path? It only worked in that context because something was different?

Comment: This method will get the real path of the file from the disk, this is the solution i usually use.